# Get value of input asynchronously while the user is still typing

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field like this

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search" />
```

and want to read the contents while the user is still typing, then show data if the search string matches it. I think I'll need an async function for it, but I don't know how to keep processing the string.

```
async function readSearchString(){
return document.getElementById("search").value;
}


function processString(cell, string)
{
   // Keep doing this
   var searchString = await readSearchString();
   if (cell.includes(searchString))
   {
       cell.visibility = "hidden";
   }  
}
```

Do I need to run the whole function in an endless loop somehow to keep getting the user input?

Comment: use input `change` or `keyup` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use input events like `onchange`, `onkeyup`, `onkeydown` etc based on your requirement.

```js
function processString()
{
   var searchString = document.getElementById("search").value;
   console.log('Search key :'+ searchString);
   // You can do your search code here
   /* 
   if (cell.includes(searchString))
   {
       cell.visibility = "hidden";
   }
   */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search"  onkeyup="processString()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. That I have done once upon time

```
var searchRequest = null; //prevent multiple unnecessary requests to the server.

$(function () {
    var minlength = 3;

    $("#sample_search").keyup(function () {
        var that = this,
        value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length >= minlength ) {
            if (searchRequest != null) 
                searchRequest.abort();
            searchRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "sample.php",
                data: {
                    'search_keyword' : value
                },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(msg){
                    //we need to check if the value is the same
                    if (value==$(that).val()) {
                    //Receiving the result of search here
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```